# case of Samstagmorgen in "Jeden Samstagmorgen lasse ich meine Haare waschen und föhnen."

Tags: grammatical-case

My friend sent me a message about her habits in German:

> Jeden Samstagmorgen lasse ich meine Haare waschen und föhnen.

Now, I see that Haare is accusative because it receives the action of the washing.

I can see the case for Haare being accusative but I'm just a bit stuck with Samstagmorgen.

Is Samstagmorgen in this case dative as it receives the action taking place? And if so, is this generally the case with most times when talking about habits on specific days of the week?

Comment: That's an *adverbial accusative* [1](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akkusativ#Der_adverbiale_Akkusativ) [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_adverbial_phrases#Accusative_nouns_with_adverbial_meaning).

Answer (score 6):

In German definite time expressions without prepositions are in the accusative

> Jeden Samstag geht er einkaufen
>   Nächste Woche mache ich das

Indefinite time without a preposition is in the genitive

> Eines Tages wird er das verstehen
>   Samstags spielt er Golf

If there is a preposition involved, then the preposition determines the case

> An irgendeinem Tag wird es passieren
>   Sie studiert seit einem Jahr in München
>   Während des ganzen Tages hat es geregnet

Comment: What about An irgendeinem Tag, in irgendeinem Jahr? Those are indefinite but dative.

Comment: @infinitezero Thank you, my answer was missing "without a preposition"

Comment: The genitive is today quite rare. "Des Nachts werde werde ich häufig vom Straßenlärm wach" sounds pretty old-fashioned. The accusative, however, is still common.

Comment: "Am Samstag wasche ich mir die Haare" is definitively dative. "Jeden Samstag wasche ich mir die Haare" is accusative. "Samstags wasche ich mir die Haare" is a degenerated genitive. "Samstag werde ich meine Haare waschen" (colloq.) is nominative - I pretty much doubt there is a rule that says *time expressions  are in the accusative*

Comment: @RHa "Nachts schlafe ich schlecht" is genitive and very common. "Eines Tages" is also still used a lot

Comment: @tofro "Am Samstag wasche ich mir die Haare" is dative because there's a preposition involved. **Definite** time expressions **without a preposition** are accusative

Comment: @PiedPiper I had three examples of other cases in my comment.

Comment: @tofro "Samstag werde ich meine Haare waschen" is also accusative (although without an article it's hard to distinguish it from the nominative). And  I covered the genitive "Samstags wasche ich mir die Haare" in my answer

Comment: @PiedPiper Can you prove that somehow? I consider that nominative.

Comment: @tofro I can't *prove* it. But consider adding an article or similar in front of *Samstag*. It would have to be accusative: "Diesen Samstag ...."

Comment: *nachts* is written without Captilazation, except for start of sentence, and it doesn't fit like a noun, syntactically. Adjectives and adverbs aren't usually inflected for case (so denke ich), so your argument is insufficient. But, in fact, the -s is trying to tell us something, so the intended implication might be viable. Likewise, "eines <nominale Zeitangabe>" is not productive, we don't say "eines <Ort>" or anything else. Latin had a locative. I haven't heard of an analogue for time, but that's what it is. That's besides the point, because there's no casing involved, just as in "every day".

Comment: @vectory Ok, then how about "Samstags schlafe ich schlecht"?

Comment: Akkusativ would mean "für den Samstag", "zu Samstag" which in some cases is applicable, but in the majority of cases it's not. Trying to subsume time under the meager four cases that are taught is not really helpful. Falling for the etymological fallacy, I have to wonder how *ad*+*cause* could become *accuse*. En. *cuss* and *curse* (unknown ety.) come to mind, hence *beschwören*, *belegen [mit einem Fluch]*, then *etwas auf einen Tag legen* might fit. "The Latin form [[accusative](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/accusative)] is a mistranslation of the Ancient Greek ...".

Comment: I think "enise Tages" is the only example of such an indefinite time in genitive :) Maybe also "einer Nacht" (never heard that though).

Answer (score 5):

The form *jede**n*** indicates that Samstagmorgen is in accusative (dative would be *jede**m***). It's always accusative when you want to use *jede/-n/-s* with a noun saying when or how often something happens:

- ich wasche mein Auto *jede Woche*.
- sie wechselt ihren Wohnsitz *jedes Jahr*.
- wir haben uns *jeden Monat* getroffen.

Comment: Accusative is the *wen-oder-was*-Fall. You wouldn't ask *wen oder was*, not even *welchen*, but simply *wann*. That this isn't quite clear cut, and the -n/-m rule not helpful is obvious from "nächsten Dienstag, **den/dem** vierten drölften", where "der" would be acceptable, *den* would be logical, but *dem* is seen rather often, too, and I can't tell why.

Comment: @vectory Grammatical case is determined by the inflection form, not by the question.

Comment: It's not determined by the inflectional form. Try "immer Samstagmorgen". I'd argue that both cases could be nominative, and that's the only reason the later case works. You cannot lean on the preposition either, because of "Samstag wasche ich meine Haare". At the very least it can't be genitive, because just "Samstag wasche ich ..." would make "Samstag" the direct object of the washing. And accusative would make saturday the agent of the verb. "Wen lässt du deine Haare waschen?", "Jeden Samstag morgen lasse ich meine Haare waschen". Though *Welchen?* would be ambiguous, and that's ok with me.

Comment: It **is** determined by its inflectional from because grammatical case is mostly expressed through inflectional form. The thing is that in German, unlike in many other languages, inflections are expressed mostly by an article. So put an artcile in all your examples and you know which case is it. PS: "immer Samstagsmorgen" proves nothing at all, because it's not just an abstract combination without any context. Depending on the rest of the sentens, it can be nominative, dative or accusative.